# Change decimal to base 16 in c++ without using strings or existing functions

Tags: hex, decimal

I want to change decimal to base `2`, `8` and `16` by just selection and repetition structures without string and functions. My problem is with `16` because of introduce `A=10, B=11, ...`. My code is:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int num=256, sum, i, A,B,C,D,E,F;
    cout<<"Enter the number between 1-256:";
    cin>>num;
    sum=0;
    i=0;
    while(num>=8)//change base 8
    {
        sum=((num%8)*pow(10,i))+sum;
        num=num/8;
        i=i+1;  
    }
    sum=sum+((num%8)*pow(10,i));
    cout<<"              result in base 8:"<<sum<<'\n';
    num=(num)*pow(8,i);
    sum=0;
    i=0;
    while(num>=16)
    {
        if (num/16>9||num%16>9)//for change int to char
        {
            A=10;
            B=11;
            C=12;
            D=13;
            E=14;
            F=15;
        }
        else
        {
            sum=((num%16)*pow(10,i))+sum;
            num=num/16;

        }
        i=i+1;  
    }
    sum=sum+((num%16)*pow(10,i));//and my problem is here: I don't know how to show this result
    cout<<"              result in base 16:"<<sum<<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you stuck because you need hexadecimal digits A, B, C, D, E, F, and cannot use strings? The same algorithm should work **if** `num`s hexadecimal representation happens to use only digits 0 to 9.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. If the remaining was more than 9 What approach should be used?

Comment: I'm not sure. This sounds like an exercise from a course, you should ask for clarification.

Comment: To be clear, 123 is a meaningful representation of octal 0123 (=decimal 83), 567 is a meaningful representation of hexadecimal 0x567 (=decimal 1383), **but** I can't imagine a similar representation of 0x123ABC (=decimal 1194684). Maybe 10203101112, using two decimal digits to encode on base-16 digit?

Comment: I study programming on my own and this is one of the Deitel's problem in chapter 2, so it seems to ignore representation A,B,... in hexadecimal.